# Ajax.ActionLink To keep the user on page

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to generate a button that will add items to a Shopping cart but the user will stay at the same page , I tried with Ajax.ActionLink , but I I'm still redirecting the user to the cart page  (And I need him to stay and just add item )
This is the Ajax

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Add to cart", 
                 "AddToCart", 
                 "ShoppingCart", 
                  new { id = item.TakeAwayId }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "successFunction" }, "")
```

Comment: Please could you include both the JavasScript code in "successFunction" and the C#/VB "AddToCart" method in your "ShoppingCart" controller. I believe the error is possibly going to be the usage of the wrong type of ActionResult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just an alternative. Use JQuery ajax:

```
<a href="#" id="add-to-cart">Add to cart</a>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#add-to-cart").click(function(e){
        $.ajax({
            url: "/ShoppingCart/AddToCart", //url path to the controller action
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                id: "@item.TakeAwayId"
            }
        })
        .success(function(data){
            //do whatever you need to do with 'data'
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you . I think it's the easy way on this.

Comment: I forgot `e.preventDefault()` and edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just gonna take a guess at this, and suggest that "successFunction" should return false